# Move folder Auth in custom folder Admin and use the views with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to move the Auth folder in my custom folder Admin.

I created auth section with :

> php artisan make:auth

I moved the folder Auth, in my Admin folder (Views/Admin/Auth)

Now I have an error with this path mysite.com/admin/login  :

> View [auth.login] not found.

I would like to use admin.auth.login view

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
    Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');

    Route::get('dashboard',['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'AdminIndexController@index']);
});
```

How can I modified the view path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put code below inside Your `AuthController`:

```
protected $loginView = 'admin.auth.login';
protected $registerView = 'admin.auth.register';
```

Also You will need to put code below to `PasswordController`:

```
protected $linkRequestView = 'admin.auth.passwords.email';
protected $resetView = 'admin.auth.passwords.reset';
```

Basically, laravel under the hood checks if You defined custom path for views and use it if finds.

Comment: Thx !! I have an error with View [auth.emails.password] not found. But it's fixed with app/config/auth.php and modified the section 'email' => 'admin.auth.emails.password',

Comment: My problem was solved by this advice, too. I'm wondering how you found this solution, since I couldn't find anything like `$loginView` in the documentation.